# "incomplete type" when printing libpt objects in GDB

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gdb

I've installed the default `libpt` and `libpt-dbg` in Ubuntu.

But GDB can't print ptlib classes:

```
(gdb) p a_party
$5 = (const PString &) @0x7fffffffcdf0: <incomplete type>
```

Linking with '-lpt'. Actually, getting options from pkgconfig through CMake:

```
#   PTLIB_FOUND
#   PTLIB_LIBRARIES
#   PTLIB_LDFLAGS
#   PTLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS
#   PTLIB_CFLAGS
#   PTLIB_CFLAGS_OTHER

include(FindPkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(PTLIB ${PTLIB_REQUIRED} ptlib)
```

What is the condition to be able to see the members? I've also downloaded the sources of the libpt and added all its directories to the `~/.gdbinit`.

Comment: Is `PString` fully declared in any of the available headers? GDB needs to know the layout of a class to print its internals; otherwise it's just ones and zeroes for GDB, just like for the rest of us.

Comment: Yes, it's in the source path of gdb. Or it has to be in the includes? Or in the binary with the debug symbols?

Comment: The *complete* definition has to be visible in the headers. Some objects are defined *incomplete*. Take `FILE` in `<stdio.h>`: Required by all the standard functions, but only as a pointer -- and you don't need a complete definition to use a pointer-to-object. Only when you try to access the object itself does the compiler complain about "incomplete type". I assume GDB has a similar problem here.

Comment: It's a string, it's not some obscure type. The code even creates PString object on the stack at that point.